# Shuffle an array of size 4 given rand in [0,1]

Tags: arrays, random

I've tried to take the `first 4 digits after the decimal point % 4 + 1` and
rewrite the array to fit the digits.
For example, if the array is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
and rand gave 0.8765 then the new array would be `[1, 4, 3, 2]`.
The problem is what happens if i get 0.1111 and such? I could rerun `rand()` until i get a good permutation but i think there's a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could interpret each digit as an index to swap with the first element:

```js
const o = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const p = [...o];
const r = Math.random();
String(r).substring(2).split("").reduce((a, n, t) => (t = a[0], a[0] = a[n % a.length], a[n % a.length] = t, a), p)
console.log(r, "permutes", o.join(), "to", p.join());
```